# Generate a PDF view with data for printing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to generate a printable report. I'm using a PDF reporting I found in code project, you can click here: [PDF Reporting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC3) to get a better view.

The thing is that the report that I need to produce already has a form that needs to be followed that can be found here: [FORM](ftp://ftp.bir.gov.ph/webadmin/forms/1601c.pdf). I was planning on placing the form as a background image through CSS3, place the necessary data over the image and throw it to the PDF reporting controller. Problem is that when the pdf view has been generated, the background image is missing. Is it possible to actually pass an image to this PDF reporting? I already tried placing an img tag as mentioned in the site but it didn't work.

Is this a good solution or is it better if we recreate the form from scratch. If you have other approach to this problem, I'd be glad to hear your suggestions.

Oh and by the way, we are using mvc3, razor view.

Update: We are also using entity frame work and asp.net 4.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you think my answer satisfies you, you should accept it. Do you know how StackOverflow works? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to think about [Microsoft Report Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6442).
You have a proper designer, very easy to use, and you can generate PDF files as well.
You can find a good tutorial [here](http://gotreportviewer.com/).
In your situation it would be better to map each field of the report as a parameter so you do not have to create a dataset.

Comment: There is no report Viewer for MVC 3... I believe.

Comment: @Kevin: I am afraid you're wrong cause I am using it. There's a link in my answer where you can download it.